# SCCM Client Push FAIL - Win2000 box

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2000, sccm

When trying to install the SCCM client onto a Windows 2000 box, the install fails.  The install script is run through a batch file (CONTENTS: `\\mdop\SCCM_client\ccmsetup.exe /mp:MDOP /logon smssitecode=MID smsslp=MDOP`) hosted on a public area of the network.  This script has worked for all machines (mostly Win2003 Server).  I've tried enabling all the common services it requires (BITS, IIS Admin, Windows Installer), but it still only runs for a second or two then quits.  Here's the piece of the log file where it errors out:

```
[LOG[Couldn't get directory list for directory 'http://MDOP/CCM_Client/ClientPatch'.  This directory may not exist.]LOG]! time="13:55:53.618+300" date="06-30-2009" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="1676" file="ccmsetup.cpp:6054"
```

Full Log: http://paste-it.net/public/gb11732/

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling MSXML6 (available from http://MDOP:80/CCM_Client/i386/msxml6.msi) and then reinstalling it onto the machine. I have no experience with it, but my gut thinks that might help.

From the directory where you've downloaded MSXML6.msi

```
msiexec /x msxml6.msi
msiexec /i msxml6.msi
```

I'm seeing forum posts, etc, with other people having the problem and no good resolution strategies.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you can browse that URL from the client; the log states that's the source of the error, so have a look at it.